# Streambuilder in CustomScrollView. A ListView in a SliverToBoxAdapter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create the following view:

[image: View]

**1.** Is the `CustomScrollView`

**2.** Is a `StreamBuilder` with a `ListView` as it's child

I want to build this view, but have a hard time creating it because a `StreamBuilder` widget has to be a child of af `SliverToBoxAdapter` in order to be in the `CustomScrollView` but the child of the `StreamBuilder` is a `ListView` which doesn't fit in a `SliverToBoxAdapter`. The thing is, a `ListView` has to be implemented as a `SliverList` when it's a child of a `CustomScrollView` Is there a widget unbeknown to me which can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this:

```
CustomScrollView(
...
slivers:[
  ...
 StreamBuilder(
  ...
 ListView)
]
)
```

if so， you can try this way：

```
CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [   buildReportList()],
            ),


...

 buildReportList() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<ReportsList>>(
        stream: _homeBloc.reportList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SliverFixedExtentList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text('hello');
              }),
              itemExtent:100,
            );
          } else {
            return SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```